# IoT logging ; tags vs meta data vs discover

Tags: system-architecture, microsoft-windows-iot

I'm looking for some guidance on what to log for a pressure sensor data packet. There's a 100 values in "Pressure Data" and I'm currently printing out all the limits and calculated values used in the sw that assess the trace (24 key:value pairs, only showing 2 + SW version in the example below).

So the question: The 24 limits and other algo stuff are static for a SW version, so I'm not sure if there is a better way of discovering the limits instead of sending them with every packet?

JSON schema:

```
{
    "ID": "P001",
    "Name": "Boiler Pressure",
    "Pressure Data": [42, 47, 139...]
    "Hi Limit": 60,
    "Low Limit": 30,
    "SW Version": 1.03
    ....
}
```